# uilabelの後ろの幅が文字数が増えると広がっていく

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

お世話になります
すごい細かい話なのですが、ちょっと気になってしまってますので、質問させてください

uiviewの上にuilabelを乗っけて、文字列を表示してるのですが、後ろの余白が、文字数に応じて広がってしまい、なんだろう、という感じになっております

```
var tagv = TagCloudView.instance()
tagv.createTag(label, with_color: UIColor(netHex: 0xffa014))

var size:CGSize = tagv.tag_text.text!.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)])

// タグのサイズを取得
if Int(size.width) + 30 > Int(max_width) {
    tagv.tag_text.frame.size.width = CGFloat(max_width - 30)
    tagv.frame.size.width = CGFloat(Int(tagv.tag_text.frame.size.width) + 30 - margin)
} else {
    tagv.frame.size.width = size.width + 30
}
```

実際表示されてる画面は
[image: キーワード一覧]
文字が４文字、５文字、６文字と徐々に後ろの幅が広くなっていっています。
こちらの後ろの幅を揃えたいのですが、どうしたらよろしいでしょうか。。。
よろしくお願いいたします。(tagv.tag_textがuilabelです)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appleのフォーラムにも質問したところ、
view hierarchy debugというものを教えてもらいました（知らなかった）
そこで、viewのxibファイルをautolayoutにして、文字の長さに応じてwidthのconstraintをセットしたら、綺麗になりました

お騒がせしました
以下を参考にしました
http://blog.morizotter.com/2014/02/14/auto-layout-by-code/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252583/how-do-i-set-the-constraint-of-width-programmatically-in-swift
http://blog.atrac613.com/2015/01/28/debug-view-hierarchy/